# Why is Flutter IconButton onPressed not working?

Tags: flutter

My app has an option to sign in with Google, a OTP, and Apple, along with a normal email and password. I have a section at the bottom of the sign-in screen with all of the buttons to log in with socials but they stopped calling the functions for some reason. They are three `IconButtons` wrapped in `Containers` for background and shape and they worked fine until all of a sudden they didn't. There is also a `TextButton` to create an account under those that isn't working but the `ElevatedButton` and `TextFormFields` above them work fine.  The only thing I changed was some UI but nothing that should have affected them. There are no kinds of errors when I press them, just nothing happens.

Code for social buttons:

```
Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: const Border(
                      top: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC), width: 3),
                      bottom: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC), width: 3),
                      left: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC), width: 3),
                      right: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC), width: 3)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Sign in with socials',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: const Color(0xFF6B6FAB).withOpacity(0.75),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF7157A0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (kDebugMode) {
                                print('otp');
                              }
                              showBarModalBottomSheet(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      const PhoneAuthScreen());
                            },
                            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidMessage,
                                color:
                                    const Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.75)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF7157A0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (kDebugMode) {
                                print('apple');
                              }
                              AppleAuth.signInWithApple();
                            },
                            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.apple,
                                color:
                                    const Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.75)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: const Color(0xFF7157A0),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (kDebugMode) {
                                print('google');
                              }
                              signInWithGoogle();
                            },
                            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.google,
                                color:
                                    const Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.75)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: PROBLEM: "...they worked fine until all of a sudden they didn't".   SUGGESTION: 1) Comment stuff out until it "works" again. 2) Carefully make one change at a time.  3) If you find the "breaking change", post back what you've found.  4) In any case, consider using Git and [git stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) to frequently save your work-in-progress (to make it easy to back out changes whenever necessary).  Using an IDE like Visual Studio Code makes this easy :)

Comment: Add code related to kDebugMode. Maybe it can cause a problem.

Comment: try to run (flutter clean) in the terminal, also close the emulator, then wipe its data, and run your project. This sometimes work

Comment: try  1. flutter clean  2. flutter pub get  3. hot reload

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you for those suggestions, I will definitely try to learn to use Git for saving different versions. It turns out the issue was pretty dumb... the whole `SigninForm` widget I created was in a `Container` and I had the height set to 250. After adding all of the sign-in methods the form was actually larger than that height so to get the lower buttons to work I just needed to set a larger height.

Comment: I've tested the snippet and tap event is working fine on this tree button, It would be better if you provide a minimal full widget that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
showBarModalBottomSheet(
   context: context,
   builder: (context) => const PhoneAuthScreen());
 )
```

Have you created a custom method by name showBarModelBottomSheet? My guess is you created a method by mistake on this class. If not then please use`showModalBottomSheet`. Remove bar from the code above. So it should be like this

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
   context: context,
   builder: (context) => const PhoneAuthScreen());
 )
```

Comment: The `showBarModalBottomSheet` method is part of a package I am using. It's essentially the same as `showModalBottomSheet` but customized. I've been using that method way before this issue so I highly doubt it's the cause.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Kaushik Chandru - The OP resolved the problem: "It turns out the issue was pretty dumb... the whole SigninForm widget I created was in a Container and I had the height set to 250. After adding all of the sign-in methods the form was actually larger than that height so to get the lower buttons to work I just needed to set a larger height. "

Comment: Oh thats nice. Thought it was a big issue lol. Glad its solved now